# How do I tell R package Limma what to use as "targets" in read.idat()?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, data-analysis, bioconductor, limma

I am analyzing some microarray data. For each donor, I have a "before intervention" and an "after intervention" idat file. I have successfully read these into R using the Limma package with the read.idat() function. However, the resulting object only has one column in targets: "IDATfile". I believe that if I was using read.ilmn() I would specify a targets.txt file but I can't see this option when using read.idat(). E.g. in the [Limma user guide](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/limma/inst/doc/usersguide.pdf) Illumina example, the targets are "Donor", "Age", and "Cell Type". **How do I tell Limma what to put as targets?** I would like to have "Donor" and "Intervention".

An example of what I mean:

```
idatfiles <- dir(pattern="idat")
bgxfile <- dir(pattern="bgx")
x <- read.idat(idatfiles, bgxfile)
colnames(x$targets)
[1] "IDATfile"
```

Instead of "IDATfile", I would like this to be "Donor" and "Intervention". I can include some other columns of the original IDAT files as further targets by doing read.idat(..., dateinfo=TRUE), but I don't know how to edit these columns to make them "Donor" and "Intervention":

```
[1] "IDATfile"   "ScanInfo"   "DecodeInfo"
```

Let me know if any more info is needed, really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to simply edit colnames you can use:

```
colnames(x$targets) <- c("Donor")
```

But I think rows are samples in the target dataframe so is that really what you want?

[http://web.mit.edu/~r/current/arch/i386_linux26/lib/R/library/limma/html/EList.html](http://web.mit.edu/%7Er/current/arch/i386_linux26/lib/R/library/limma/html/EList.html)

> targets data.frame containing information on the target RNA samples.
> Rows correspond to samples. May have any number of columns.